# C# XNA Screen scrolling

Tags: c#, xna, camera, scroll, screen

Maybe I'm dumb but i tried reading the answers you guys had here, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. So I got a game (a Stargate shooter) where you drive a space ship and you gotta destroy all of your opponents. The problem I'm having is I don't really know how to create a map and how to move my camera around it according to the ship's position. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need some online video tutorial on youtube, or a beginner book :) Try Nathan videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JReWPy7RVUI

Comment: Yes, I read one tutorial and it was not there. I'll try the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably resolved this yourself already, but if not then I highly recommend going over to [David Amador's page](http://www.david-amador.com/2009/10/xna-camera-2d-with-zoom-and-rotation/) on the subject. As an added bonus, David is active on the site and replies directly to your questions (within 10 minutes usually).